# Send stepper to position and back AccelStepper

Tags: arduino-uno, stepper

At the moment I am working on a code that should send a plateau to a certain position and back. The plateau is being moved by the stepper, in my case a Nema 17 with a [Polulu DRV8825](https://www.pololu.com/product/2133) driver. Everything is hooked up correctly. 
My goal is to press '4' on the keyboard and that then the stepper moves to a certain position. However, I am not succeeding in this. I am using AccelStepper and at the moment I have the following code:

```c
#include <AccelStepper.h>

AccelStepper stepper(1, 5, 4);

int spd = 1000;    // The current speed in steps/second
int sign = 1;      // Either 1, 0 or -1  
int buttonState = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(1000);
  stepper.setSpeed(1000);
}

void loop()
{
  char c;
  if (Serial.available()) {
    c = Serial.read();
    if (c == 'f') {  // forward
      sign = 1;
    }
    if (c == 'r') {  // reverse
      sign = -1;
    }
    if (c == 's') {  // stop
      sign = 0;
    }
    if (c == '1') {  // super slow
      spd = 100;
    }
    if (c == '2') {  // medium
      spd = 900;
    }
    if (c == '3') {  // fast
      spd = 1000;
    }
    if (c == '4') {
      //not working, does anyone know how to do this?
      stepper.moveTo(500);
    }
    stepper.setSpeed(sign * spd);
  }
  stepper.runSpeed();
}
```

Does anyone have tips or know how to achieve this?

Thanks is advance!

Comment: You need to call `stepper.run()` instead of runSpeed, for moveTo to work.

Answer (score 1):

[Gerben's comment](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/18604/send-stepper-to-position-and-back-accelstepper#comment34648_18604):

> You need to call stepper.run() instead of runSpeed, for moveTo to work.

provides the answer. The updated code is:

```
#include <AccelStepper.h>

AccelStepper stepper(1, 5, 4);

int spd = 1000;    // The current speed in steps/second
int sign = 1;      // Either 1, 0 or -1

int buttonState = 0;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(1000);
  stepper.setSpeed(1000);
}

void loop()
{
  char c;
  if (Serial.available()) {
    c = Serial.read();
    if (c == 'f') {  // forward
      sign = 1;
    }
    if (c == 'r') {  // reverse
      sign = -1;
    }
    if (c == 's') {  // stop
      sign = 0;
    }
    if (c == '1') {  // super slow
      spd = 100;
    }
    if (c == '2') {  // medium
      spd = 900;
    }
    if (c == '3') {  // fast
      spd = 1000;
    }
    if (c == '4') {
      //not working, does anyone know how to do this?
      stepper.moveTo(500);
    }
    stepper.setSpeed(sign * spd);
  }
  stepper.run(); //You need to call stepper.run() instead of runSpeed, for moveTo to work. – Gerben
}
```